# Dotnet build gets 401 error in getting nuget packages using powershell

Tags: asp.net, .net, powershell, build, nuget

I'm working on a project with several ASP.Net Web Api projects. To run these apis locally, I have a powershell script that builds them and deploys them to my local IIS.

If there's no updated nuget packages to pull down, the script works great.

However, the dotnet build fails to get the nuget packages if there are updated packages.
What is the proper way of setting up the credentials to nuget.org so it can pull down the packages.
This script is just for my local development and will not be used in Azure DevOps.